# Split a treeSet value set to arrays and then add to an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, treemap

I am fairly new to Java and I have been trying to use TreeSets, all was well however, I want to split the values of a specific key to indiviual string. i.e.

```
Alice,3,1,6,3,6
```

would become:

```
Alice is a string

3 is a string

1 is a string
```

and then I would like to add them to an array so that:

```
Alice,3,1,6,3,6

Jon,5,3,1,6,5

Alice and Jon are in ArrayNames

3 and 5 are in ArrayScore1
```

I basically need the value to split into their values and then transferred to an array
All help is welcomed and appreciated

Thanks

Silver

Comment: Show some of your work!

Comment: Hmm, maybe `TreeMap`, not `TreeSet`?

Comment: There's no keys and values in `TreeSet'. Everything is a key here. What is index [4]?

Comment: If you have `TreeSet` with `String` elements these elements are sorted in lexicographic order. As I undrestood, your `TreeSet` contains strings like `Alice,3,1,6,3,6`. And how do such strings can be sorted by special "index"? Do you use any `Comparator`?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan 
yes I used a comparator as below:@Override public int compare(String e1, String e2) { int e1val = Integer.parseInt(e1.split(",")[4]); int e2val = Integer.parseInt(e2.split(",")[4]);; if (e1val < e2val){ return 1; } else { return -1; } } }

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell, but I think you actually want to create a `Map<String, List<String>>` from a `Set<String>`.

Try this:

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(); // doesn't matter what type of Set
// NOTE: You must populate the list somehow
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
set.stream()
  .map(s -> s.split(",")) // String to String[]
  .<String[], List<String>>map(Arrays::asList) // convert String[] to List<String>
  .forEach(a -> map.put(a -> a.get(0), a -> a.subList(1, a.size())));
```

Avoid using arrays unless you absolutely have to: Always prefer using Collections.

If you only want to do one thing with the data (ie you don't need to keep the map), instead of collecting the data, call `.forEach()` instead, for example:

```
...
.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.get(0) + " has scores " + s.subList(1, s.size()));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code above may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: How would I go about outputting it index by index?

Comment: @silver try `map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " has scores " + v);`

Comment: Then your set is empty. I have edited the answer to make it clear you must put stuff in the set.

Comment: What do you mean "do something to k, v"? The forEach method is being passed the key and value of every map entry. Do whatever you need to do with them.

Comment: I have been able to get it to output, the error was on my side, however all the data I had sorted has become unsorted.

Comment: see edited answer - LinkedHashMaps iterate in insertion order

Comment: there is an error:  The method put(String, List<String>) in the type Map<String,List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> a) -> {}, (<no type> a) -> {})

Comment: @silver fixed. I forgot to code the lambda parameter.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but the same error exists its at map.put

Comment: Try latest edit. Sometimes you have to explicitly type the method

Comment: Why would this make a difference?